# No HTTPS functions found. Use firebase functions:shell

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I've been trying all day to get my functions to run locally but I don't know why it keeps saying I have no functions. I'm using typescript, so I ran `tsc` in the functions folder, then ran `sudo firebase serve --only functions`, but I get this error:

```
i  functions: No HTTPS functions found. 
Use firebase functions:shell if you would like to emulate other types of functions.
```

[image]

**Edit:** I tried serving the function without `sudo` but I get permission issues:

[image]

Comment: You have a warning message: "Failed to emulate helloWorld".  What does the error log file say?

Comment: It says "connection refused." 
 See here: https://gist.github.com/AskYous/d4112ab86fa0731a0f168ccde3e1a306

Comment: Any reason why you're using sudo to run `firebase serve`?  That shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I get permission issues. I put a screenshot in the post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't know why it worked, but I just restarted VSCode (because it had an update) and everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have nothing running on the same port that the Firebase function emulator is trying to run on, in my case I had a Docker container running on port 5000. Once I stopped it and started the Firebase function emulator it served the function correctly.