# Function load error: Code could not be loaded

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I try to run `sudo functions deploy login --trigger-http`, I get the following error:

> ERROR: Function load error: Code could not be loaded.
>
> ERROR: Does the file exists? Is there a syntax error in your code?
>
> ERROR: Detailed stack trace: module.js:549

But I already have an `index.js` file in `/lib`. I don't know if there's a bigger issue than this because I just solved my [last issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53329108/1404347). Or this could be unrelated. I've been having a hard time gettings functions running locally with debugging:

[image]

Comment: firebase command line syntax is `firebase deploy --only functions:myfunction`

Comment: @RonRoyston I'm using functions cli tools: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator/wiki/Debugging-with-Visual-Studio-Code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer. I had to change directories into the functions folder.

Answer (score 0):

Additional answer to make more clear.
In my case, i'm trying to run my function inside google functions-emulator then this error happen.
But with short solution from @AskYous, i still got a little confuse.

So like @AskYous answer, we have to enter into functions folder, then type like this:

```
C:\FirebaseFunctionTypescript\functions>functions deploy api --trigger-http
```

The "api" is our exported functions inside index.ts file.
[image: Sample project]